# cin input user for dynamic allocation of array of strings

Tags: c++, string, dynamic-memory-allocation

i'm new at this, learn c++, try to dynamic allocate a array of strings and input every string by the user. so at first, the user input the number of strings, and then put every string using `cin>>`

```
int main() {


    int numberOfTeams;
    char** Teams;

    cout << "Enter the number of teams " << endl;
    cin >> numberOfTeams;

    Teams = new char* [numberOfTeams] ;

    
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTeams; i++) {
        
            cin >> Teams[i];
                
    }

    delete[] Teams;

    return 0;
}
```

the program throw me out after cin one string.
the error i get is :

```
 Exception thrown: write access violation.
**_Str** was 0xCEDECEDF.
```

i cant use "string" veriable, only array of chars.

thank you all

Comment: You need to allocate `Teams[i]` before `cin >> Teams[i];` remember `Teams[i]` is a char pointer however you did not initialize it to point to anything.

Comment: thanks for the comments all. how do i allocate 'Teams[i]'  before cin?, and unfortunately it is school rule not to use 'string'

Comment: Try to assing to Teams[i] before you ```cin >> Teams[i];```.  Use new or malloc, like ```Teams[i] = new char[512]``` or ```Teams[i] = (char *)malloc(512)```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this

```
const int MAX_STRING_SIZE = 1024;

int main() {


  int numberOfTeams;
  char** Teams;

  std::cout << "Enter the number of teams " << std::endl;
  std::cin >> numberOfTeams;

  Teams = new char*[numberOfTeams];
  for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTeams; i++) {
    Teams[i] = new char[MAX_STRING_SIZE];
    std::cin >> Teams[i];
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < numberOfTeams; ++i) {
    delete [] Teams[i];
  }
  delete [] Teams;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @EY178 Be sure to use delete [] Teams, but not delete Teams[i] like in another post, cause it could result in memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

A char** is a pointer to an array of character pointers. First thing you do is allocate the array of character pointers with
`Teams = new char*[numberOfTeams];` Teams now points to the first char* out of numberOfTeams char* pointers. Your mistake is that for each char* pointer in the array, you did not perform an allocation. Here is the correct solution.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {

    int numberOfTeams;
    int teamNameLength = 32;
    char **Teams;

    cout << "Enter the number of teams " << endl;
    cin >> numberOfTeams;
    Teams = new char*[numberOfTeams];

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTeams; i++)
    {
        Teams[i] = new char[teamNameLength];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTeams; i++) {
        cout << "Enter team name " << i+1 << endl;
        cin >> Teams[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTeams; i++) {
        delete[] Teams[i];
    }
    delete[] Teams;

    return 0;
}
```